# Fill a matrix in parallel

Tags: python, loops, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a question about how to fill a matrix in parallel. I'm trying to do it in Python row-by-row. But the time to do it in parallel is worst than the sequential processing time. How can I do it efficiently? Note: I need to know the value of the indices (*i* and *j*).

**Squential**

```
def something(pos, size):
    global matrix

    numpy.zeros(shape=(size, size))

    for i in xrange(size):
        matrix[i][i] = 0.0

        i_lat = pos[i]['lat']
        i_lon = pos[i]['lon']

        for j in xrange(i + 1, size):
             matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j] = _matrix_update(pos, i_lat, i_lon, i, j)

def _matrix_update(pos, lat, lon, u, v):
    return 0.0 if u == v else euclidean_distance((lat, lon), (pos[v]['lat'], pos[v]['lon']))
```

**Parallel**

```
def something(pos, size):
    global matrix

    numpy.zeros(shape=(size, size))

    for i in xrange(size):
        matrix[i][i] = 0.0

        i_lat = pos[i]['lat']
        i_lon = pos[i]['lon']

        Parallel(n_jobs=mp.cpu_count())(delayed(_matrix_update)(pos, i_lat, i_lon, i, j) for j in xrange(i, size))

def _matrix_update(pos, lat, lon, u, v):
    global matrix
    matrix[u][v] = matrix[v][u] = (0.0 if u == v else euclidean_distance((lat, lon), (pos[v]['lat'], pos[v]['lon'])))
```

Comment: I think it can be done in a vectorized way, without looping. Can you update your question with a sample input matrix (5 rows should be enough), a short description of what do you want to do with this data and desired resulting matrix?

Comment: you may also want to check [those](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/spatial.distance.html) _vectorized_ functions

Comment: In this case, I can't use Numpy, because the euclidean_distance function is a proper method for this case and no framework implement it as I need.

Answer (score 2):

Your code raises a whole bunch of questions, too many to put in comments.

```
def something(pos, size):
    global matrix
```

What is `matrix`?  Why `global`?  Since you are mutating it you don't need the global even it is defined outside this function.  But I'd prefer seeing it passed in and out as argument.

```
    numpy.zeros(shape=(size, size))
```

What's the point of this statement?  Why aren't you assigning the result to anything?  It is supposed to be `matrix = np.zeros(shape...)`?  In that case `matrix` is created in the function, and should be in a `return matrix` statement, not the global.

```
    for i in xrange(size):
        matrix[i][i] = 0.0
```

If `matrix` is 2d array, then index it with `matrix[i,i] = 0`.  But if it was created with the `zeros` expression, this diagonal is already 0.

```
        i_lat = pos[i]['lat']
        i_lon = pos[i]['lon']
```

What is `pos`?  The syntax suggests that it is a structured array, the 'lat' field of the ith record.  It's not a list of dictionaries?

```
        for j in xrange(i + 1, size):
             matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j] = _matrix_update(pos, i_lat, i_lon, i, j)
```

So here you are setting symmetric values.  When done iteratively this is a good way of doing it.  The are `np.tri...` functions for dealing with upper and lower triangular arrays.

```
def _matrix_update(pos, lat, lon, u, v):
    return 0.0 if u == v else euclidean_distance((lat, lon), (pos[v]['lat'], pos[v]['lon']))
```

Given how you iterate on i and j, `u==v` never occurs, so the update can be simplified to

```
j_lat, j_lon = pos[j]['lat'], pos[j]['lon']
matrix[j,i] = matrix[i,j] = euclidean_distance((i_lat, i_lon), (j_lat, j_lon))
```

I don't expect these changes to speed up the calculation, but they should make it clearer.

What is this `Parallel`?  You need to give more information on what module or package that you are using.  Is this something that tries to use multiple cores?  Is it something that known to work with `matrix` (what ever it is)?

What is this `euclidian_distance` function?  Imported from somewhere else?